# Maven build dependencies before checking nexus

Tags: java, android, maven, nexus, android-espresso

I am building my multi module project using the command

```
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests
```

This project has 3 maven modules: A, B, C.

A doesn't depend on anything.

B doesn't depend on anything.

C depends on A.

I am getting a very weird scenario where maven sees that C depends on A and then instead of building A from the sources it decides to check nexus for it (as my .m2 local repository doesn't contain A) and it fetches an old version of A. Then it goes on building everything, but when it reaches C it uses that old version of A and fails.

If I run my build in offline mode then it works great, but the problem is that I do want to deploy my new artifacts in nexus when I am done, and maven offline mode restricts me from doing that.

I am wondering if I am doing something really weird, this seems like a pretty easy to handle scenario.

Edit: If I login to nexus and i manually delete all the old artifacts and then build  with the command provided above, everything works fine.

Edit 2: C depends on A with a "provided" scope, something like :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>application</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

(version is declared in dependencyManagement section of the parent pom).

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing the behaviour you describe. If your project is setup correctly, maven should use the output from "A" to build "C".
I think you might have an issue in your POM file.

Comment: Show your pom file i assume your inter module dependencies are simply wrong, cause what you describe is a typical symptom if this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to the Espresso Testing framework in android. One of the android dependencies in the pom.xml was set with `<scope>test</scope>` instead of `<scope>provided</scope>` and that was causing the trouble described.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Commit A so that you get the latest changes and C builds fine
2. Make C depend on a specific version of A. Update the version of A and make C depend on it

Comment: As for option (1), I don't want to commit A before building the rest of the project. I want one command to do everything. As for option (2), can you give me an example? Let's say that C depends on A-version1. I run the command, then A-version1 is not found on nexus, it is build locally, A build succeeds, B build succeeds C build succeeds. Then next time I run the same build, A-version1 is already in nexus, but it is the old version of A. So maven downloads that and fails like i mentioned in my question, doesn't it ? I can't keep changing the version of A that C depends on after every build !

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to just say: "Hey look, the dependencies that C depends on are about to be built so use those instead of checking nexus!"